# Assigning ODD/EVEN Class to span with Jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just stuck up with assigning ODD/EVEN Class to span with Jquery.

**QUESTION UPDATED**

I need to add class to span inside col div as **"odd"/"even"** . check the commented class name  and order of execution & i need to assign in this way.

**Expected Output: Class name are in comments**

```
<section>

    <div class="col">
        <span></span> <!-- ODD --> (1)
        <span></span> <!-- ODD --> (5)
        <span></span> <!-- EVEN--> (8)
        <span></span> <!-- ODD--> (10)
        <span></span><!-- EVEN--> (11)
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <span></span><!-- EVEN--> (2)
        <span></span><!-- ODD-->  (6)
        <span></span><!-- EVEN--> (9)
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <span></span><!-- ODD --> (3)

    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <span></span><!-- EVEN--> (4)
        <span></span><!-- ODD-->  (7)
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Everyone please check the commented class name. Im not assign odd even or each col. im looking for odd even overall spans

Comment: If you iterate span collection on your own, you can have such a control. See my answer.

Comment: How are the `<span>`s generated?

Comment: Please explain required order of execution before you get downvoted.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić in html, each col are arranged in verticle next to next. so each first span inside each col lies first. No i need to calculate the odd even for the first spans inside all col

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MbEVa/).

```
$(function(){
    $('.col > span:odd').addClass('odd');
    $('.col > span:even').addClass('even');
});
```

Use `.col >` to make sure you're not effecting other spans on the page.

I've updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MbEVa/5/) according to the new requirement.

```
$(function(){
    var currentClass = 'odd';
    var currentRow = 0;
    var updated = true;

    while(updated){
        updated = false;
        $('.col').each(function(index,value){
            var currentSpans = $(value).find('span');
            if(currentRow < currentSpans.length){
                currentSpans.eq(currentRow).addClass(currentClass);
                currentClass = (currentClass == 'odd') ? 'even':'odd';
                updated = true;
            }
            if($(value).is(':last-child')){
                currentRow++;
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: @Yontam Omer Great Dude. Works as Expected.

Comment: np mate :) I've made it a little more efficient - take a look on the new code.

Answer (score 4):

Basic answer:

```
$('span:odd').addClass("odd");
$('span:even').addClass("even");
```

Better performance answer:

```
$('span').filter(':odd').addClass("odd");
$('span').filter(':even').addClass("even");
```

**EDIT**
Including Jquery docs info: http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Because :odd is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :odd cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :odd to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":odd").

**EDIT**
To answer the edited question:

```
var rowIdx = 0;
var actualClass = "odd";
$('.col').each(function(){
  var $col = $(this);
  var $span = $col.find("span").eq(rowIdx);
  if ($span.length > 0) {
    $span.addClass(actualClass);
    actualClass = (actualClass == "odd" ? "even" : "odd");
  }
});
```

Comment: Updated answer to explain why is better performance the second option.

Comment: How about using nth-child directly in the css. That would provide the best performance right?

Comment: But nth-child Works for the container, I mean, He needs even/odd in different containers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more control, you can iterate spans on your own.

```
$(function() {
    $.each($("div > span"), function(idx, span) {
        if(idx % 2 == 0)
            $(span).addClass("even");
        else
            $(span).addClass("odd");
    })
})
```

**EDIT**: now it's tested

Answer (score 0):

You can also use nth child property of css, assign same class to each span and use even odd to perform the operation

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: w3schools.com shoul be prohibited